# Can I stop master row changes from closing the details?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid enterprise with angular 6. I have a master/detail setup with a custom detailCellRenderer.

The issue I am having is that the detail closes if any data changes in the master row. I cannot find any documentation on stopping that or even detecting that it is happening.

here is my grid definition:

```
ag-grid-angular(
  style="height: 100%;width: 100%",
  class="ag-theme-balham",
  [gridOptions]='gridOptions',
  [enableSorting]="true",
  [enableColResize]='true',
  [unSortIcom]='true',
  [enableFilter]='true',
  [rowSelection]="'single'",
  [suppressRowDrag]='true',
  [animateRows]='true',
  [sideBar]='sideBar',
  [statusBar] = 'statusBar',
  [enableRangeSelection] = 'true',
  [floatingFilter] = 'true',
  [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]='true',
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)",
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)",
  [rowData]="alarms",
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs",
  [pagination]="true",
  [paginationAutoPageSize]='true',
  [frameworkComponents]='frameworkComponents',
  [masterDetail]="true",
  detailCellRenderer = "alarmInstanceSubtableRenderer",
  [getContextMenuItems]="getContextMenuItems"
  )
```

here is my renderer:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ICellRendererAngularComp} from 'ag-grid-angular';
import {AlarmInstance} from "../../../../../../../lib/models/alarm-instance/alarm-instance";

@Component({
  selector: 'vfms-alarm-instance-subtable-renderer',
  templateUrl: './alarm-instance-subtable-renderer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alarm-instance-subtable-renderer.component.styl']
})
export class AlarmInstanceSubtableRendererComponent implements OnInit,ICellRendererAngularComp {

  alarmInstance: AlarmInstance;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  refresh(params: any): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.alarmInstance = params.data
  }

}
```

`refresh()` does not make a difference whether true or false. In fact it is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your grid definition:

```
[rememberGroupStateWhenNewData] =  true
```

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#keeping-group-state